# qml application not reporting javascript errors

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I wasted so much time cause I was using this line

```
return root.wdidth / 3
```

instead of

```
return root.width / 3
```

in JavaScript function in my QML app. **Why it doesn't give any warning or error** when I run my app ?
Is there any setting I need to do to prevent such pitfalls ?

I'm using Qt Creator 4.13 and Qt 5.15.

Comment: I agree with you, it is really annoying. Have you tried `Tools->QML/JS->Run Checks`?

Comment: @JarMan it looks like its completely broken. its reporting wrong errors on correct code while neglecting the real wrong code. e.g I'm getting `error: Invalid property name "columnWidthProvider". (M16)` for TableView which is false error

Comment: You can also try `qmllint` which comes with Qt but isn't integrated in Qt Creator. But there is no perfect solution.

Comment: @JarMan thanks qmllint does catch `root.wdidth`